# How to change the text of selectbox after its selected?

Tags: angularjs, html

here fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/TU6tp/47/

Here i am getting if i select any option in dropdown i will get same in in selectbox text but i need "Change portfolio" There should be select anyor change Portfolio.

If u see fiddle u will understand easily what i am trying to say

**CODE**

```
    <select 
    ng-model="selectedItem" 
    ng-options="o.label for o in selectables">
    </select>

   <p>Portfolio manager: {{selectedItem.value}}</p>
   <p>Group: {{selectedItem.manager}}</p>
   <p>Group name: {{selectedItem.groupname}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ng-change` with two scope variables `selectedItemx` and `selectedItem`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3151cupp/)

```
<select 
   ng-model="selectedItemx" 
   ng-options="o.label for o in selectables" ng-change="changeLable()">
</select>

$scope.changeLable = function() {
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.selectedItemx;
    $scope.selectables[0]['label'] = "CHANGE PORTFOLIO";
    $scope.selectedItemx = $scope.selectables[0];           
}

// this is the model that's used for the data binding in the select directive
// the default selected item
$scope.selectedItemx = $scope.selectables[0];
```